# How can I change the body from a list in my code in a request.post while loop, changing the body in each loop

Tags: python, json, loops, post, request

Here is what I want to achieve:
Send API POST request to the API endpoint in a loop, and with each loop send a different value within the json body from mylist until the loop goes down each value from my list, one by one.

mylist = (1234, 5213, 4151)

```
my_numbers = json.dumps(mylist)

While True:

    upgrade_api = requests.post('http://api.com',headers={"content-type": "application/json", "Authorization": token},
    json=[{my_numbers}]
```

Basically I want the body in the json request to change in each loop from my list. My coding sucks but it works for what I need it for.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do `json=[{"numbers":my_numbers()]` don't call a variable the same as a lib, more when you're using this lib ^^ Also explain better please, call the request for each value in you `mylist` ? This is unclear

Comment: @azro that was my mistake. This api post request changes parameters using json REST api, and I want to change the parameters for multiple nodes per say who use the same api request and want to run the script until all the "nodes" in my list receive the request one by one.

Comment: Did not understand. Please edit your post (no comment) and explain the steps, and answer : Do you want to do the requst for each value of `mylist` and pass the value in the request ?

Comment: I tried to explain to the best of my abilities. Hopefully it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to send them indivially, why did you try to send the whole list ?

---

You may do it this way, you may need to specify the `key` for the number in the JSON part

```
mylist = (1234, 5213, 4151)
headers = {"content-type": "application/json", "Authorization": token}
for value in mylist:
    upgrade_api = requests.post('http://api.com', headers=headers, json={"number": value}
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! If you dont mind, how do I put a waiting period of 3 seconds between each request to a number?

Comment: @dkohn1337 for that you can look by your self. `time.sleep(3)` If you don't do effort you'll never progress ;)

Comment: I appreciate it. I started with python about a month ago and still learning the ropes.

Comment: @dkohn1337 you can now think bout accepting the answer so ;)